# How to structure my homeowner's association database?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm trying to do an accounting software specialized in homeowners' associations (I had to search the translation for this, just an association of the owners of one building that pay a fee for maintenance and other building needs) for my personal use, since that has been my work more than ten years.

Thing is I read and read more and more, have designed my database trying to be normalized and what not: 47 tables 35 of which will have the same two columns, an integer Id for the association (the building) and another integer Id for the tax year.

At first I thought to made different tables just putting that two data in the name of the tables, but I read dynamic table names are a bad idea. Then I read a lot about multi-tenancy and partitioning, but I'm still confused and right now I get more confused the more I read.

Right now I can think of four possibilities:

- Whatever, don't overcomplicate it, add that two columns to all the tables.
- Add the two columns and do partitions with that columns, doing composite primary keys when needed.
- Do different databases: one for the few tables that don't have the association and the tax year, and one per association per tax year.
- Go back to the idea of dynamic table names.

Now, I insist, the more I read the more confused I am. Some people say it depends on the number of rows, others say it depends on the "balance" between  `SELECT`s and `UPDATE`s, others say various databases are a maintenance nightmare, others say various databases is better, others say you are trying to do performance things at the design phase...

Given my years of experience working on that specialized accounting, I know that I can't assure any size or quantity of the data. While one building can have five residents with a ridiculously small amount of data, the next one can have one, three or five hundred of residents with hundreds of thousands of accounting transactions per tax year (number which would multiply across the different tables, of course). Also, you can work at a building one year and be fired, but work at another one more than ten years: buildings keep constantly coming and going, sometimes even coming back years after.

All the thing is really inconstant by nature, since every person have their own way of thinking but all of them have a house to live, therefore a single building have people of all the types, personalities, professions and ages you can imagine, all mixed up.

So, am I overcomplicating it? Should I shut up, do it the simpler (add the two columns) and then measure the results and modify? Should I pick up one of the other possibilities? Should I keep reading until I get satisfied with a solution (ouch, more reading? :S)? Maybe don't strictly stay with one way and do it different ways with different building needs?

It seems that I'm not able to find a strict rule about all this, so any help or advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Given the comment of Luke Ryan, here is a link to a preliminary diagram I do on app.quickdatabasediagrams.com of the [building/tax year dependant tables](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5gCDTxJQ0VNeVhGU0FSXzhCR28), without both referred columns. I'm doing it on MYSQL workbench too but I haven't finished it yet.

Also, the tables with no dependency are [these ones](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5gCDTxJQ0VNU2FnMGVKUHJKT0k/view?usp=sharing). At this last diagram, the primary key of tables called "*comunidad*" and "*ejercicio*" are the columns that the other tables would be dependant.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a diagram of your schema illustrating the problem?

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to understand. If your concern is having foreign keys in many tables, this might not be an issue. Or it might indicate poor schema design. There isn't really enough information to help.

Comment: I've added diagrams as you ask.

Comment: My concern is that almost all of the tables should have the same two columns. It include having so many foreign keys as you say, but also the amount of data (two more columns per row on the 75% of the tables), performance of having so many tables with that index, updates and inserts with that two index plus the usual ones, having to write the exact same `where`clauses again and again, etc.

Comment: Broken link: schema does not exist. https://app.quickdatabasediagrams.com/#/schema/MSUqR6fHC0uJvkVczTlnEA

Comment: Remember I'm an amateur, I can imagine what will happen of course, but I'm not sure how all of it will effectively affect the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143010/discussion-between-luke-ryan-and-nox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to Nox in chat and recommend the following:

1. Try to find a model that represents the domain and doesn't require peppering the building id and tax year everywhere e.g.
   [image]
2. Don't add foreign keys for tax year and building to all of the tables. This will make the schema complex and impact performance. You can find a model that doesn't require this.
3. Don't use different databases for the data, this will make administration e.g. backing up etc more difficult.
4. Don't dynamically generate tables as this will make your queries dynamic and difficult. It will also make administration difficult e.g. schema updates as they will need to update a many identical tables.
5. Keep reading and learning about data modelling :-) e.g. http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html